# Recursive Promise.all with a snapshot in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, es6-promise

I have the following structure on my firebase database:

[image]

I need to get the values of the keys `pin`. For that I'm working with a recursive function like this:

```
let pins = [];

const normalize = (snapchot) => {
  snapchot.forEach(function(child) {
    if(child.val().pin) {
      pins.push(Promise.resolve(child.val().pin));
    }
    else normalize(child);
  });
  return Promise.all(pins);
}
```

And now, call the `normalize` function:

```
normalize(snapshot) // snapshot represents the data from the firebase db
  .then(p => {
    console.log(p); // [ 'mi-pin-agosto', 'mi-pin-julio' ]
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error
  })
```

And it works, but when I debug that code, I see that `return Promise.all(pins);` gets called more than one time. I only need to be called only once, after the `foreach` have been completly finished;  that's with the idea for the case of performance, because the `snapshot` data it's more large than the see it in the image I show.

Any ideas ???

Comment: normalize is recursive - of course it gets called more than once

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `Promise`s at all ... is `child.val().pin` a promise? is there **any** asynchrony  regarding the code in `normalize`?

Comment: @JaromandaX `child.val().pin` it is not a promise, I'm convert it to a promise. I asked this, because I have seen another answers here related on how to use this.

Comment: why would you attempt to make synchronous code asynchronous? there's absolutely nothing to gain from doing this

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok you are right, just I want to know if I can call the `Promise.all(pins)` only once, and after all the `forEach` has been complete within all the recursive times?

Comment: not recursively you can't - you would have to redesign the code - say, something like `const normalize = (snapchot) => {
    const process = x => {
        let ret = [];
        x.forEach(function(child) {
            if(child.val().pin) {
                ret.push(Promise.resolve(child.val().pin));
            } else {
                ret = ret.concat(process(child));
            }
        });
        return ret;
    });
    return Promise.all(process(snapchot));
}`

Comment: though, I'd write `normalize` in such a way that it did not introduce asynchrony, and if I felt the bizarre need to do so, I'd `Promise.all(normalize(snapshot)).then(.... rest of your code ...)` - because the array passed to Promise.all doesn't even need a single promise to work

Comment: @JaromandaX Please, can you write both of your ideas as an answer?

Comment: First, can you explain why you (tried to) use Promises?

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right, you have made me see the reason in why it is not correct to use promises in code that is already synchronous. Sometimes my head is getting crazy :) But, if you still want to answer with both of your examples, I will accept it.

Comment: I thought there was an underlying reason you tried to make it asynchronous - which you wouldn't be anyway :p hang on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to only use `Promise.all` once you can have the *recursive* function as a function "inside" `normalize

```
const normalize = (snapshot) => {
    const process = x => {
        let ret = [];
        x.forEach(function(child) {
            if(child.val().pin) {
                ret.push(Promise.resolve(child.val().pin));
            } else {
                ret = ret.concat(process(child));
            }
        });
        return ret;
    });
    return Promise.all(process(snapshot));
}
```

This code also doesn't require a `global` array to store the results

However, as there is nothing `asynchronous` about any of the code you are calling - dispense with the Promises inside `normalize`

```
const normalize = (snapshot) => {
    let ret = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        if(child.val().pin) {
            ret.push(child.val().pin);
        } else {
            ret = ret.concat(normalize(child));
        }
    });
    return ret;
};
```

If you really have to use Promises for this code, you can simply

```
Promise.all(normalize(snapshot))
.then(p => {
    console.log(p); // [ 'mi-pin-agosto', 'mi-pin-julio' ]
 })
.catch(err => {
    // handle error
})
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for your help and voluntary time ! Greetings to Australia :p